# How to change battery mode on my laptop?

Tags: 11.10, battery

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 last day and tried to change battery mode( change balanced mode to power save mode like on windows ) on my laptop , but I don't know how to do it.

Is there anyway to do that? Is there any program to do that?

Comment: Can you make clear what you mean by changing the battery mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any program that can make modes for the battery.

But you can always change the settings by clicking on the battery icon (in the upper right corner), then click "Power Settings", change what ever you want to.

To access and modify the brightness settings, open the dash, go to System Settings, and click on Brightness and Lock.